# How to focus first input while other inputs are disabled in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to focus the first input while the others are disabled. The next input will be enabled after it was tabbed or selected.
Is there a way for this in javascript?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form:first *:input[type!=hidden]:first').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="ex-input" type="text" placeholder="name" />
  <input class="ex-input" type="text" placeholder="age" />
  <input class="ex-input" type="text" placeholder="city" />
  <input class="ex-input" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I think the code is working fine.

Comment: I mean, what I like are the other fields will be unclickable when the first input is focused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this. Hope it helps.

```js
$('.form-control').click(function() {
$(this).parent('div').next().children( '.form-control' ).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="name" />
</div>
<div>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="age" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
<div>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="city" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
<div>
    <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: My code looks like this https://jsfiddle.net/bqf8ptrm/6/
<br/>
How can I get the class name when they are placed in different divs?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sfuex89c/

Please find the fiddle, Hope it is useful. I'll also updated the snippet of my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot click on disabled elements, and can't attach events directly on it.

One solution is to add disabled class and style your inputs like they are disabled. Please find the code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ex-input[type!=submit]').on('click, focus', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('disabled')
    $('.ex-input[type!=submit]').not(this).addClass('disabled')
  })
});
```

```css
input.disabled {
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="ex-input" type="text" placeholder="name" />
  <input class="ex-input" type="text" placeholder="age" />
  <input class="ex-input" type="text" placeholder="city" />
  <input class="ex-input" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your taking time on this but i'm looking for another solution