# How to get the class name within multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to create other fields to be unclickable when the first input is focused but it seems it doesn't work. I did an illustration so that it will be understandable and my code looks like this. 
May I know where I did it wrong?

```js
$('.form-control').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('div').next().children('.form-control').prop('disabled', false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div>
        <div class="name">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="age">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="age" disabled="disabled" />
        </div>
        <div class="city">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="city" disabled="disabled" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="submit">
        <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your HTML looks a little bit wonky. Are you sure the `name` should have a different grandparent, while the `age` and `city` should have the same grandparent? (it's quite fine to have such an HTML structure, just want to make sure it's deliberate)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374375/how-to-focus-first-input-while-other-inputs-are-disabled-in-javascript/58375785#58375785 ------ Copy of this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to focus first input while other inputs are disabled in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374375/how-to-focus-first-input-while-other-inputs-are-disabled-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
$('.form-control').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('form').find('.form-control:disabled:first').prop('disabled', false);
})
```

`$(this).parent('div')` returns something like `<div class="name">` and then using `.next()` will not find anything since it don't have any siblings.

**Demo**

```js
$('.form-control').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('form').find('.form-control:disabled:first').prop('disabled', false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <div class="name">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="name" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="age">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="age" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
    <div class="city">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="city" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="submit">
    <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This will select the focused (clicked) input as well.

Comment: Hello, Carsten.
Thanks it worked. I was hitting my head so many times for this.